# How to show datepicker in android

Tags: android, button, datepicker

I'm new to Android development so I apologize beforehand if you find my question too simple.

I followed the tutorial here to create a datepicker:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

It works but I'm wondering if there is a way to show the datepicker without having to click on a button? 
Basically I want the datepicker to automatically show at the exact same location as my button right now. I'm thinking of just have an empty TextView and call showDatePickerDialog there but that obviously doesn't work.

Here is the xml part for my current button:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/pick_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick_date" 
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Basically I want the datepicker to automatically show at the exact same location as my button right now." Have you tried adding `<DatePicker ... />` to your layout?

Comment: Yea it does nothing for me though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a DatePicker widget in Android. If you're using Eclipse, check out the "Graphical Layout" of an XML file to see the available widgets.

This should do the trick:

```
<DatePicker 
    android:id="@+id/pick_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I tried that but it does nothing. I'm assuming I need to call "showDatePickerDialog" somehow...

Comment: Nevermind. I added DatPicker tag and it shows automatically. THank you!